# Change one value based on the range of a value in another column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do something like this, wherein I would change the values of another column based on the value of that row in another column

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv("test.csv")
df.loc[df.meters == 30, 'Class'] = 5
```

However, I would like to use something like a range of values as the condition rather than a set condition, something like this:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv("test.csv")
df.loc[df.meters <= 30 and df.meters >= 15, 'Class'] = 4
```

Comment: wrap each condition in brackets ```()``` and use ```&``` instead of ```and``` in ```loc``` -->```df.loc[ (df.meters <= 30) & (df.meters >= 15), 'Class'] = 4```

Comment: use brackets and replace and with &, then you can add any conditions you want.